# What is the difference between a transaction with and without signatures?

Tags: asch-development, asch

When i send an transaction to `peer/transactions` i can send it  with and without signatures. Both transaction are accepted. What is the difference.

Example; Create a new chain / dapp by using asch-js

Situation 1: using signatures (and a `transactionid`):

```
 function createDApp(options, secret, secondSecret) {
    var keys = crypto.getKeys(secret);

    var transaction = {
        secret: secret,
                type: 200,
        amount: 0,
        fee: constants.fees.dapp,
        recipientId: null,
        senderId: crypto.getAddress(keys.publicKey),
        timestamp: slots.getTime() - globalOptions.get('clientDriftSeconds'),
                args: [options.name, options.description, options.link, options.icon, options.delegates, options.unlockDelegates], 
                signatures: []
    };

    transaction.signatures.push(crypto.sign(transaction, keys));

    if (secondSecret) {
        var secondKeys = crypto.getKeys(secondSecret);
        transaction.signatures.push(crypto.secondSign(transaction, secondKeys));
    }

    transaction.id = crypto.getId(transaction);
    return transaction;
}
```

Situation 2: no signatures

```
function createDApp(options, secret, secondSecret) {
    var keys = crypto.getKeys(secret);

    var transaction = {
        secret: secret,
                type: 200,
        amount: 0,
        fee: constants.fees.dapp,
        recipientId: null,
        senderId: crypto.getAddress(keys.publicKey),
        timestamp: slots.getTime() - globalOptions.get('clientDriftSeconds'),
                args: [options.name, options.description, options.link, options.icon, options.delegates, options.unlockDelegates], 
                signatures: []
    };

    return transaction;
}
```

Both transaction are accepted (and create a new chain). So what is the difference and what is best practice?

Comment: Does it work if you sign the transaction and send it to `peers/transactions` without the `secret` property?
If you provide the secret in the transaction the blockchain will be able to self sign the transaction.

Comment: hi @mathayk, the `secret` in the `transaction` is not required, but the transactions is also accpeted without the `secret` and with an empty `sigantures[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand the `api/transactions` endpoint is mainly for **unsigned** transactions (like your 2nd example). Therefore you need to provide the `secret` property. Otherwise the ASCH blockchain can't sign your unsigned transaction.

In your first example you are **signing** the transaction by yourself, therefore you don't need to send the `secret` property to the `peer/transactions` endpoint.

From a security endpoint it is better to sign your transactions locally. So no malicious node can steal all your funds when you send your `secret` the a blockchain endpoint.